# Why did Rabbi Akiva write down Torah She Baal Peh?

Tags: mesorah-tradition, oral-torah

In the Rambam's introduction he writes:

> וחיברו חכמי משנה חיבורין אחרים, לפרש דברי התורה:  רבי הושעיה תלמידו
>   של רבנו הקדוש, חיבר ביאור ספר בראשית.  ורבי ישמעאל פירש מאלה שמות עד
>   סוף התורה, והוא הנקרא מכילתא; וכן רבי עקיבה חיבר מכילתא.  וחכמים אחרים
>   אחריהם חיברו מדרשות.  והכול חובר קודם התלמוד הבבלי.

That Rabbi Akiva wrote a Mechilta. Presumably, the Rabbi Yishmoel is the one identified by the Rambam earlier as well since he doesn't clarify anyone else, even though he authors a work starting from Shemos and someone much later authors Bereishis.

Rabbi Akiva and Rabbi Yishmoel are several generations before Rabbeinu HaKadosh. And although the Rambam allows that things were written for personal use before Rabbeinu HaKadosh, these works don't appear to be personal notes.

Comment: The quote doesn't say anyone wrote anything.

Comment: @mevaqesh, That is exactly how the Rambam uses the word חיבור. רבנו הקדוש חיבר המשנה.  ומימות משה ועד רבנו הקדוש, לא חיברו חיבור שמלמדין אותו ברבים בתורה שבעל פה; אלא בכל דור ודור, ראש בית דין או נביא שיהיה באותו הדור, כותב לעצמו זיכרון בשמועות ששמע מרבותיו, והוא מלמד על פה ברבים. I realize that others hold Rabbeinu HaKadosh didn't write anything down, but the Rambam is very clear.

Comment: No. Chibber meant composed. One can compose something and also write and disseminate it, or compose something and not write and disseminate it.

Comment: @mevaqesh, If you want to support such a contention in an answer, go ahead. But reading that into the Rambam is, generously, a דוחק גדול. Most of his uses of חיבור become nonsensical when reading that way.

Comment: No his usage is not nonsensical at all. It always means to compose. There were works composed that were written and disseminated and those composed that weren't disseminated. Until Rabbenu Hakadosh there were no hibburin _that were disseminated_ but there were hibburin _that were not disseminated_.

Comment: Compare this to the Spanish version. of the Iggeret Rav Sheriara Gaon (which Rambam would have been familiar with): ולא הוה חד מן הראשונים דכתב מדעם עד סוף יומי דרבינו הקדוש. Even though the Spanish version writes that until the end of his life, it also states that R. Yehuda R. Nehemiah and R. Shimon composed halakhic literature  והני ברייתא ותופתא וספרא וספרי הילין 
 ברייתא כלהו הוו תנו להו רבנן קמאי ואתו ר' יהודה ור' נחמיה וליקוטון כל הדא . Clearly it means composed but didn't write.

Comment: @mevaqesh, " Until Rabbenu Hakadosh there were no hibburin that were disseminated but there were hibburin that were not disseminated." But that isn't at all what the Rambam writes, rather רבנו הקדוש חיבר המשנה. ומימות משה ועד רבנו הקדוש, לא חיברו חיבור שמלמדין אותו ברבים בתורה שבעל פה; אלא בכל דור ודור, ראש בית דין או נביא שיהיה באותו הדור, כותב לעצמו זיכרון בשמועות ששמע מרבותיו, והוא מלמד על פה ברבים.

Comment: +1 But how does this jive with the gemara that his students wrote the various midrashim in accordance with his views?

Comment: @Yishai I have to agree with mevaqesh that חיבור does not mean 'write'. Mevaqesh is translating it as 'compose'. A better translation might be 'organize'. Each of the Sages had a uniques scheme for organizing the vast data set of the oral tradition. They wrote personal notes for themselves, which they didn't share with others and only passed along their methods orally, face to face. They called these personal notes 'Megillot Setarim'.

Comment: The translation of חיבור as 'organize' is in keeping with how Rashi explains Gittin 67a which begins: "תניא איסי בן יהודה היה מונה שבחן של חכמים". There it mentions Akiva's unique style of organization quoting Avot d'Rabbi Natan. If I recall correctly, I think this is discussed in some detail by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan in the first volume of his Handbook of Jewish Belief.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, I don't disagree, but here the Rambam is using it as organize in writing. Otherwise he isn't saying anything. ומימות משה ועד רבנו הקדוש, לא חיברו חיבור שמלמדין אותו ברבים - so all those personal notes aren't organizations? The novelty isn't that he taught from writings? והוא קיבץ כל השמועות וכל הדינין וכל הביאורין והפירושין ששמעו ממשה רבנו, ושלמדו בית דין של כל דור ודור, בכל התורה כולה; וחיבר מהכול ספר המשנה. Is a ספר also not a book?

Comment: @YaacovDeane,  גם חיברו הגאונים שבכל דור ודור, חיבורין לבאר התלמוד - the organization is the point, not the writing?  לפיכך קראתי שם חיבור זה משנה תורה - did he not write a book? The whole introduction uses חיבור as in putting it together in writing. The etymology of the word doesn't change that.

Comment: @Yishai When the Rebbe is teaching about the uniqueness of Rambam's 'Magnum Opus', he explains it as the unique way that Rambam organized and systematized the subject matter as in 'authored' (מחבר) or 'authorship', not that he 'wrote' (כתב) it down on paper. This same type of understanding is also applied to Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato. This is to distinguish from an 'editor' (מלוקט). A sefer (ספר) is a 'composition' and is associated with the idea of an original work. If you look at the end of halacha 14, which you quote, it says the listeners wrote it down from Nasi's oral lecture.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, all of that doesn't justify saying the Rambam is using the word חיבר to say that someone composed something without writing it down. Sure כתב would simply mean transcribing it (as that is how you made copies), but the Rambam holds that Rabbeinu HaKadosh wrote (or instructed a scribe to write his dictation) the Mishna, and every use of the term חיבר in that introduction refers to creating a written book, with no qualification or addition of כתב and that by doing חיבור Rabbeinu HaKadosh did something not done for 33 previous generations.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, claiming that the two problematic instances of חיבור suddenly doesn't mean written, just oral composition, is beyond a desperate answer.

Comment: @Yishai What Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi did was synthesize all the different schools of oral tradition from Moshe Rabbeinu to his own generation into a single, unified school. That school is what is presented in the Mishnah. He gave it over orally in public. The students wrote it down, just like the Rebbe gave his Ma'amarim orally and the Chozrim wrote it down. That similarity isn't by accident. The written copies of the Chozrim were compared and synthesized into a single version which was presented to the Rebbe to review, correction and amendment. That text, called מוגה, was then printed.

Comment: @YaacovDeane, the method of composition is rather tangential to the point here. Rabbeinu HaKadosh did something novel - he made (personally or directed, it doesn't matter) a written work to study the Oral Torah. That is what the Rambam is saying. And this was a departure of 33 generations of practice. Except that 5 generations earlier the same thing was done (seemingly). Why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe most scholars (if not all) do not interpret the Rambam as suggested in the question. Instead, the Rambam is referring to the Mechilta of R. Shimon [bar Yochai] whose collection is generally in accordance with R. Akiva.

The initial groundbreaking work was done by Friedmann, which he treats in his intro. to his Mekhilta edition ([here, s.v. מעתה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38922&st=&pgnum=67)), and demonstrated that Rambam was referring to what we have today 'Mekhilta of Rashbi'. Later R. DZ Hoffman published his edition of the newly organized Mekhilta of Rashbi on Shemot and corroborated ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38923&st=&pgnum=4)) Friedmann's theory(ies). See also Prof. Finkelstien's perceptive take on the Rambam's phrasing here versus his phraseology in his intro. to the Mishnah ([here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1452437?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)), intimating that "Mekhilta of R. Akiva" was compiled by Rashbi. See R. Kasher ([note 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52260&st=&pgnum=12&hilite=)) for another later example of agreement (unanimous, AFAIK) on interpreting Rambam here.

Regarding the general question when the Tannaitic Midrashim assumed textual form, Albeck shows in his מבוא לתלמודים & מבוא למשנה that it was after the closing of the Talmud. Until then the texts (i.e. the lessons) were transmitted orally slowly gaining structure and organization.

Comment: That doesn't help the question. Rabbi Shimon was only one generation later.

Comment: @Yishai and so?

Comment: so why did he write down Torah She Baal Peh?

Comment: @Yishai Ah, you mean it doesn't help your new question "Why did Rashbi write down TSBP?". You'll need to first prove that he did [put pen to paper]. Rambam is merely speaking of a collection (mechilta) which follows the school of R. Akiva, ultimately ascribed to Rashbi as its refactor.

Comment: My question hasn't changed. The fact that we have the Sefer attributed to Rabbi Shimon doesn't change that 1) the Rambam thinks that Rabbi Akiva wrote it and 2) either way indicates that someone wrote Torah before the Mishna. The 20 uses of חיבר in the preface, 18 unambiguously refer to written works, and even refer to the verb applied to a book. Someone claiming that the two instances that pose a problem suddenly doesn't mean composing a written work bears the burden of demonstrating that.

Comment: @Yishai It was not clear that the question was according to Rambam in particular, rather than merely using him as the background for the question. Indeed, the question was not tagged Rambam. || As such, those who disagree with him certainly are acceptable as answers. This is completely independent of what Rambam means...

Comment: @mevaqesh, someone could give an answer that the Rambam would clearly disagree with, but a reasonable answer either accepts the premise (that someone wrote down and disseminated in some form TSBP prior to Rabbeinu HaKadosh) or demonstrates that *no one* holds that way. An answer which just quotes opinions that the answerer finds more authoritative that hold that nothing was written just isn't very interesting.

Comment: Oliver, what is said in Pirush HaMishnayos that indicates that Rabbi Shimon wrote this Mechilta (your link doesn't work for me).

Comment: @Yishai sorry about that; fixed it

Comment: Oliver, could you provide a more precise citation? I skimmed through about half of that paper and didn't see it (but I was only skimming).

Comment: @Yishai Don't have it in front of me now. IIRC it's the big note on pg. 474